# Why is my .htaccess code is not working?

Tags: php, .htaccess

My htaccess file code is not working even it is right i found on many website for this each website has same code here it is :-

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?action=$1&sub_cat=$2
```

now this thing is not working www.example.com/products/something/3/
anything else i am forgetting please help me.

Comment: you have a trailing `/` in your pattern, therefore your URL **MUST** be `.../products/something/3/`. Maybe you want `.../?$` to make the trailing `/` be optional?

Comment: no, I'm saying that your rewrite pattern REQUIRES there be a `/` at the end. you don't have one in your url, therefore the rule never matches.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal when i tried your code it redirects me to google means mod_rewrite is active

Comment: No, `Redirect` is **not part of mod_rewrite**.

Comment: Jon Lin is correct. Ranvijay can try again with: `RewriteRule ^ http://google.com [R,L]` instead.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal this code also redirecting me to google

Comment: That's good and could you tell me in which dir is this htaccess located?

Comment: No, your htaccess file you're adding these rules to..

Comment: what about the `RewriteBase`!

Comment: @RaviThapliyal my htaccess file is in public_html folder which is main folder and index.php also located in this folder

Comment: @RanvijayMittal do you happen to have a file called "products.php"?

Comment: @JonLin yes i have products.php

Comment: Add this as the first line in your php file: `<?php echo "WORKING!" ?>` I think you're hitting the index.php but it's not generating any data!

Comment: @MikeAnthony just forget .htaccess for a moment now for example when i write www.example.com/index.php?action=products&id=3 at this time products.php page opened and get id i.e. 3 at the index page i wrote a condition so whenever it looks action=somthing it add .php after it. now what is wrong with my .htaccess code.

Comment: @MikeAnthony it does if mod_negotiation has anything to do with it

Comment: @JonLin - sorry, deleted my comments as I saw your answer... Didn't think of that, considering the structure of the rewrite rule. You are correct indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a `products.php` file and your URL looks like `www.example.com/products/something/3/`, a module called "mod_negotiation" is processing the request *before* mod_rewrite can. The `Multiviews` option will allow mod_negotiation to try to "guess" what a request is for, and it sees `/products/` in the URL and the file `/products.php` and assumes that's what the request is for, serves the request via the `products.php` script and mod_rewrite never gets a chance to do anything.

Solution?

Turn off multiviews:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

by adding that option anywhere in your htaccess file.

Comment: @RanvijayMittal make sure your links (to scripts/css/images/etc) are all either absolute URLs or add a relative URL base in the header of your pages: `<base href="/" />` because the new URL format changes the relative base

Comment: like in this way  <head><base href="/" /></head> ?

Comment: @RanvijayMittal in the header, inbetween the  `<head> </head>` tags